# On Schoen and Yau's proof of the positive mass theorem: extracting a minimal surface in the limit

Tags: riemannian-geometry, uniform-convergence, mathematical-physics, minimal-surfaces, arzela-ascoli

I'm reading Schoen and Yau's [1979 paper on the Positive Mass theorem](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=681F7E0AEA37238B21EB0827E86CF7D2?doi=10.1.1.625.8612&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I'm having trouble understanding the proof of how they extracted a minimal surface as the limit of solutions to the Plateau problem.

So far (at the end of page 7 in the PDF) , for a fixed end $N_k$ (identified with $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus an open ball) of the Riemannian 3-manifold $(N,g)$, they found a sequence of embedded smooth surfaces $S_{\sigma}$, which are g-area minimizers spanning $C_{\sigma}$: The euclidean circle of radius $\sigma$ lying on the x-y plane. Defining the "cylinder"
$$A_q = \{x \in N_k : (x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2 \leq q^2\})$$
and the "slab"
$$E_h = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x^3| \leq h \}$$
They were able to show that, for any $\sigma > q$:
$$S_{\sigma} \cap A_{q}\subseteq E_h \cap A_{q} $$

They next quote the following interior regularity estimate, where $U_{r}(x)$ is the geodesic ball of radius $r$:

> There exists a number $r_{0}>0$ so that for any $x_0 \in S_{\sigma}$ with $U_{r_0}(x_0)\cap C_{\sigma} =\phi $, $S_{\sigma} \cap U_{r_0}(x_0)$ can be expressed as the graph of a $C^3$ function whose derivatives up to order three are uniformly bounded for any $\sigma$.

Using this, they claim that we can choose a sequence $S_{\sigma}^{q}\cap A_{q}$ converging in the $C^2$ topology, as $\sigma \to \infty$. I'm stuck at this point. I think the Ascoli-Arzela theorem has something to do with this, but can't seem to figure out the details. Any help is much appreciated.